# How to add a CSS class to SAVE and CANCEL (editview) buttons SugarCRM

Tags: css, class, button, sugarcrm

I'd like to add a class to the buttons CANCEL and SAVE in edit view , in order to add an icon inside the button.
I already add a class in Header.tpl for the whole buttons (add border etc), but no way to add specific class to cancel or save button

Thanks for help

Dimitri

**ANSWER :**

in editviews.php from your module I add a div for the CANCEL button for example.

So no need to change the header.tpl

```
[..]
'form' =>
array (
'buttons' =>
array (
0 => 'SAVE',
1 => 'CANCEL',
//THIS LINE IS THE CUSTOMIZATION:
2 =>
array (
'customCode' => '<div class="icon-accept"></div>',
   ),

 [....]
```

Comment: At least put your css or fiddle link here.

Comment: hi, I's not a CSS issue, I have to add a class to the header.tpl (smarty) I think or the edit views.php. I can override the original css, but with no adding my class don't work

Comment: Am not clear with your quetsion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in editviews.php from your module I add a div for the CANCEL button for example.

So no need to change the header.tpl

```
[..]
'form' =>
array (
'buttons' =>
array (
0 => 'SAVE',
1 => 'CANCEL',
//THIS LINE IS THE CUSTOMIZATION:
2 =>
array (
'customCode' => '<div class="icon-accept"></div>'',
   ),

 [....]
```